# std::vector - optimization during game loop

Tags: c++

I'm simply having some questions regarding optimization of my design.

All the game objects in the game inherit from the base class

```
class Environment;
```

The game iterates over a vector and updates and renders each object:

```
for (auto& env : this->listEnvironment)
{
    if (env->GetIsMarkedForDeletion()==false)
    {
        env->Update();
        env->Render();
    }
}
```

as long as the object is not marked for deletion.

So this is what I'm wondering, is it better to create a separate loop and delete all the objects from the vector that are marked for deletion, simply leave them be in the vector and don't render them or should I do it in the same loop as the rendering?

From what I understand the performance decreases a lot if i resize the vector during the loop but I might have misunderstood this.

Comment: My guess is that the execution time of updating and rendering far outweighs the check for deletion.  You can always profile for better information.

Comment: Ye but what if i start deleting stuff, reset the iterator and everything during the game loop, then what? Its a question of iterating over the vector multiple times or run it once and start removing stuff from it. Question is, which one is faster

Comment: You're asking us to guess.

Comment: Profile.  Comment out the calls for updating and rendering.  Mark all items as deleted.  Measure the execution time for 1E9 iterations.  This will be the "worst case" for all items delete.  Divide the execution time by 1E9, which gives the average execution time for the loop.

Comment: @Drew Dorman If that's the case then I'm sorry but I really though there was a right way and a wrong way in this scenario that has been tested before.

Comment: @nilo This is good news for you.  Write it in the way that you're most comfortable.  Profile and optimize only when you know it's not fast enough.  Good luck!

Comment: Why not use [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) with a predicate to shift all the deleted items to the end of the vector.  Then you can choose whether to actually delete them, or just leave them in and iterate over the returned range.

Comment: @nilo Performance is mostly irrelevant here. Do the thing that is easiest and leads to the cleanest code. I'd vote for erasing it all at once using `remove_if`.

Comment: remove_if sounds really interesting, didn't even think about it. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that gives you almost zero overhead in keeping your environment list clean:

edit 2:
probably as efficient as it gets. Thanks for the inspiration in the comments:

```
struct Environment {
    virtual bool GetIsMarkedForDeletion() const;
    virtual void Render() const;
    virtual void Update();
};

struct World {

    using environment_container = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Environment>>;
    environment_container listEnvironment;

    static bool is_removable(const environment_container::value_type& ptr)
    {
        return ptr->GetIsMarkedForDeletion();
    }

    void do_update_and_render()
    {
        listEnvironment.erase(std::remove_if(begin(listEnvironment),
                                        end(listEnvironment),
                                        is_removable),
                              end(listEnvironment));

        for (auto& env : this->listEnvironment)
        {
                env->Update();
                env->Render();
        }
    }
};
```

edit: in response to AlchemicalApples' concern over memory fragmentation, version 2 is offered, which does not deallocate memory unless the environment grows in size beyond it's high watermark:

```
struct Environment {
    virtual bool GetIsMarkedForDeletion() const;
    virtual void Render() const;
    virtual void Update();
};

struct World {

    using environment_container = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Environment>>;
    environment_container listEnvironment;
    environment_container survivingEnvironment; // = {}

    void do_update_and_render()
    {
        if (survivingEnvironment.capacity() < listEnvironment.size()) {
            survivingEnvironment.reserve(listEnvironment.size());
        }
        for (auto& env : this->listEnvironment)
        {
            if (env->GetIsMarkedForDeletion()==false)
            {
                env->Update();
                env->Render();
                survivingEnvironment.push_back(move(env));
            }
        }
        survivingEnvironment.swap(listEnvironment);
        survivingEnvironment.clear();   // note-does not clear memory so fragmentation is prevented
    }
};
```

the original is here for comparison:

```
struct Environment {
    virtual bool GetIsMarkedForDeletion() const;
    virtual void Render() const;
    virtual void Update();
};

struct World {

    using environment_container = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Environment>>;
    environment_container listEnvironment;

    void do_update_and_render()
    {
        environment_container new_objects;
        new_objects.reserve(listEnvironment.size());
        for (auto& env : this->listEnvironment)
        {
            if (env->GetIsMarkedForDeletion()==false)
            {
                env->Update();
                env->Render();
                new_objects.push_back(move(env));
            }
        }
        swap(new_objects, listEnvironment);
    }
};
```

Version doing the update in-place, without allocating a potentially large new vector:

```
void do_update_and_render_in_place()
{
    auto cursor = this->listEnvironment.begin();
    auto sentry = this->listEnvironment.end();
    while(sentry != cursor)
    {
        auto &element = **cursor;
        if(element.GetIsMarkedForDeletion()) { break; }
        element.Update();
        element.Render();
        ++cursor;
    }
    if(sentry == cursor) { return; }
    auto trailing = cursor; // beginning of deleted elements
    ++cursor;
    for(; sentry != cursor; ++cursor) {
        auto &element = **cursor;
        if(false == element.GetIsMarkedForDeletion()) { continue; }
        element.Update();
        element.Render();
        swap(*cursor, *trailing);
        ++trailing;
    }
    this->listEnvironment.erase(trailing, sentry);
}
```

Comment: @nilo Are you sure this is the answer you want? This requires an extra (potentially large) allocation during each call to `do_update_and_render`, which can cause memory fragmentation and other performance issues.

Comment: @AlchemicalApples your concern is noted. A small modification will solve that concern... standby...

Comment: Good starting point.  The improvement over this answer would be to make the compaction in-place, no need to allocate a new vector.

Comment: @EdMaster see version 2 :)

Comment: @RichardHodges still allocating an entirely new vector, I went ahead and submitted an edit to your answer with an example of in-place update

Comment: @EdMaster thanks ed - with your inspiration I have also added another version - in place using only std algorithms.

Comment: @RichardHodges I like your edit #2 better than my in-place version because it is very clean and more understandable.  However, your edit #2 traverses the vector twice, so, it is not as efficient as traversing only once.

Comment: @EdMaster That's something we'd have to profile to check. Although it traverses twice, it's only calling each operation once. In addition, it does not need to manage the movement of sentinels (this is being done under the covers by the stl). I think if we profiled it we'd find that it would optimise to almost exactly the same code.

Comment: @RichardHodges Here's why traversing twice versus once might make a difference: traversing once, for non-deleted elements makes three virtual method calls on the same instance; probably the virtual method call latency penalty is paid in the first; two traversals are two virtual method calls from cold instances.  Sure, it should be profiled.